# CakePHP Controller::persistModel and Form Automagic

Tags: optimization, cakephp, forms

I am developing an app using the CakePHP framework.  I just recently read an article that said enabling

`var $persistModel = true;`

could lead to performance gains.  As I am working on a development server I thought I'd give it a try.  Lo and behold the site was slightly faster at the cost of losing form automagic.  For example, all users have group_ids, but instead of the form input being displayed as a drop-down, it was a simple textfield.  However, when I disabled `$persistModel` form automagic worked as normal once again.

I have made sure to set a variable called `$groups` in the view, and the User model has a proper `$belongsTo` association.

Does anybody have any insight as to why this might be happening?  Is there a way I can use `$persistModel` and form automagic at the same time?  I'm obviously missing something here.

Thanks a lot!

-wes

Comment: Is there a reason you're concerned about the performance increase (or does persistModel have other advantages as well)?  How much faster was it?

Comment: It wasn't too much faster.  I'm not overly concerned with performance.  I've optimized my queries and database indices to eliminate the big stress.  I'd just like the thing to be faster.  As this post might hint, I'm not willing to sacrifice features that make Cake great just for a few milliseconds.  But if I could reclaim those millis I might as well.

Answer (score 2):

For those Googling this (like myself), the setting has been removed in CakePHP 2.0.

> `$persistModels` does not exist anymore, the table structure is cached either 
>   in files or in APC cache if available (the faster APC cache is used if 
>   detected)

From http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/f241ff38a2368032